# ie6 css display incorrect

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

hello
i am using css menu and it looks fine in ff and ie7/8 but in ie6 the menu is not positioning correctly. it is supposed to sit to the right but for some reason it is moving to the left. i have included screenshots and my css for the menu and would be grateful if someone could tell me where the error is? many thanks

```
#menu
    {
        width:425px;
        height:33px;
        float: right;
        margin:133px 51px 0 0;
        padding:0px;
    }
#menu ul
    {
        width:525px;
        height:33px;
        float:left;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        display:block;
    }
#menu ul li
    {
        width:76px;
        height:33px;
        float:left;
        margin:0 1px 0 0;
        padding:0px;
        display:block;      
    }
#menu ul li a.menu
    {
        width:76px;
        height:26px;
        float:left;
        margin:0px;
        padding:7px 0 0 0;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:13px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#FFF;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:none;
        background-image:url(../images/menu.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }   
#menu ul li a.menu:hover
    {
        width:76px;
        height:26px;
        float:left;
        margin:0px;
        padding:7px 0 0 0;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:13px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#FFF;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:none;
        background-image: url(../images/menuover.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;        
    }
```

screenshots:

correct menu spacing: http://i51.tinypic.com/9kytxf.png

incorrect menu spacing: http://i54.tinypic.com/fldpow.png

Comment: i am not sure but try position:relative.

Comment: @user455318 still the same. thanks

Comment: I realize this isn't helpful, but I felt obligated: http://ie6countdown.com/

Comment: thank you jimmy. i totally agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your sizes don't add up correctly and IE's handling of that differs from the others.  Notice, for example, that `#menu` only has a width of `425px`, but its `ul` has a width of `525px`.  So perhaps FF is clipping the overflow but IE isn't.

Try removing the widths from everything but the innermost elements (`#menu ul li a.menu` for example) and let the rest be automatically sized.  Or at least start by removing/fixing the width of `#menu`.

Comment: i removed the width from the menu div and it moved it just fractionally right. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be the old [Double Margin Float Bug](http://www.cssnewbie.com/double-margin-float-bug/), when you have a float with a margin in the same direction.. i.e. left float/left margin or right float/right margin  IE5/6 was known to double the margin

so on:

```
#menu {
        width:425px;
        height:33px;
        float: right;
        margin:133px 51px 0 0;
        padding:0px;
    }
```

try adding `display:inline;` to the above rule, if that's it, it's a safe fix to leave in place as all other browsers rightly ignore the display property on a floated element

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a proper doctype at the beginning of the HTML file using your CSS. IE6's quirks mode is terrible! For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Take note that a proper (non-html5) doctype will have a URL pointing to the dtd. If your doctype isn't correct, fix it and see if that helps.

Comment: this is what i have before the head. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> thanks

Comment: You're good to go with your doctype then. Your issue is straight up CSS related. The reason I suggested checking the doctype is that many people I have seen over the years fall victim to the quirks mode by not having a proper doctype, which can lead to weird CSS behaviors, especially with floats. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html for more details.

Comment: which still leaves me scratching my head :-)